# The set of numbers of the form $q_1+q_2^2+q_3^3+q_4^4+q_5^5$ where all $q_k$ are primes.

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures

Conjecture:

> All prime numbers greater than $109$ is of the form
>   $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^5q_k^k$, where all $q_k$ are primes.

The conjecture is extracted from the question and answer here:
[Annoying primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486943/annoying-primes)

Tested for all primes $<70,000$.

The exceptional primes seems to be
$\{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,109\}$

> Are there heuristic arguments for the conjecture?

Also:
All primes except $\{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,37,43,53,61,67\}$ seems to be of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^4q_k^k$.
All primes except $\{2,3,5,7,11,13,37,61,127\}$ seems to be of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^3q_k^k$.

Both cases tested for primes less than $10,000$.

Comment: I neither understand the downvote nor the closevote.

Comment: @Peter: Maybe some kind of misunderstanding about a duplicate?

Comment: If every odd number $n>351$ can be expressed by $n=a^3+b^2+c$, where $a,b,c$ are primes, the claim is true. And chances are not bad that this is the case. According to my claulations, for $351<n\le 10^6$, such a representation exists.

Comment: @Peter: maybe you should post your interesting conjecture as a separate question?

Comment: It was down voted 3 hour ago and it was edited only 1 hour ago. So I will remove down vote now.

Comment: @Peter I was wondering the same thing. $p^3+q^2+r$ doesn’t seem to be enough for the evens though (it would need to happen via $q=2$) so I think you need at least 4 to get all numbers.

Comment: @Charles We do not need the even numbers, we can set $q_4=q_5=2$

Comment: @Peter It’s just a comment about minimality — if you wanted to get all (large enough) numbers, not just primes, that speaks to the exponent needed.

Comment: @Charles   The conjecture is that all PRIMES have the desired form.

Comment: @Peter Yes — I was making a broader statement about a more general question, as indeed you were in suggesting looking at representations of the form $p^3+q^2+r$. (Other broader questions are relevant, such as representations by $p+q^3.$)

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one small heuristic argument: there are no local obstructions, so lacking a good reason to the contrary, all large enough numbers should be of this form.

Another: There are $\gg x^{137/60-\varepsilon}$ representations up to $x$, and so each number has on average $x^{77/60-\varepsilon}$ representations. Since
$$
\int \exp-x^{-76/60}
$$
converges, the number of exceptions should be finite.

Comment: Please explain the second argument. How did you estimate the number of representations ?