# Is every odd integer $n>351$ expressible as $a^3+b^2+c$ with primes $a,b,c$?

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

This conjecture

[The set of numbers of the form $q_1+q_2^2+q_3^3+q_4^4+q_5^5$ where all $q_k$ are primes.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2490483/the-set-of-numbers-of-the-form-q-1q-22q-33q-44q-55-where-all-q-k-are#2490483)

would be true if for every odd $n>351$ , there are primes $a,b,c$ with $a^3+b^2+c=n$.

> Is this conjecture true , or is there at least a heuristic for it ?

Comment: $402$ cannot be so expressed.

Comment: @rogerl $402$ is not odd.

Comment: Ah. Missed that point.